# expo app can't find the path specified in ...node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, nvm

I have created an expo app using different commands and I still end up with the same error while starting metro bundler.

```
Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\bee\Documents\GitHub\walletwallie\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)   
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\bee\Documents\GitHub\walletwallie\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)   
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\bee\Documents\GitHub\walletwallie\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)        
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

wanted to install cross-spawn cause i thought it's not in my node_modules but it does exist.

I did create the project successfully before.
i had **expo-cli installed globally** for this and i was using **node 18.16.0**
but the project logged some depreciation warninigs

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
```

and a complain that expo sdk 44 doesn't support react-native 0.72. so i had to update expo with.

```
npm install expo@^49.0.0
npx expo install --fix
```

and it took care of that.
But expo complained that it doesn't support node 17 and higher.

Had to use NVM node version manager to install node version **16.20.1**
And the cross-spawn error started spawning here and there.

**Steps i've used to recreate this error:**

1.

```
npx create-expo-app --template
```

selected the blank (bare) option.

```
npx expo start --android
```

2. same step at 1) but selected blank option.

3.installed expo-cli using npm

```
expo init walletwallie
```

and got same error.

If anyone knows a better env. with a combination of (Node, NPM, Expo SDK, react-native) version to build my starter project without errors please let me know.

I'll try deleting the expo-cli package from my global npm package and try again with a local expo setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same issue since yesterday. Finally got it working.

I was able to solve the issue by running `yarn android` in powershell instead of bash as I was doing.

What was causing the issue:

The file that cannot be found is the `adb` binary which it (expo is looking for in the path specified in ANDROID_HOME environment variable (this was when I reverted to using global expo/cli - perhaps the local one is looking in the non-deprecated `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`).

I was using Bash shell and the folder specified in ANDROID_HOME env variable was using windows-style folder path, which was not handled well so it could not find the file.

Running `yarn android` in powershell (as an administrator) worked.

Hope this helps.